# Difference between prophecy and preaching relating to women. Acts 21:9, Philips daughters

Tags: prophecy, gender, pastorals

I believe women can be used in ministry. God's plan being a man as a preacher but at times using women, as Lydia in Acts foundation of the church at Philippi. But I am having a  struggle with Acts 21:9 with Philip's daughters that did prophesy.

Does that verse mean that prophesying included preaching, such as a Pastor would...and that this verse opens the door for women to be Pastors? If so, would this contradict Paul's statement that *women are not to rule over men*? (1 Timothy 2:12)

Comment: Welcome to the site, Kim.  On the Hermeneutics site, there are a couple of things to bear in mind. A particular text is to be examined. The very least the OP can do is quote the text in full (saying which Bible translation is being quoted). Then the OP needs to explain what gave rise to the query, and in this case, it would be helpful if you could set out the reasons for you claiming that prophecy and preaching have similarities. Claims need to be substantiated. Can you tell us why you think that prophesying and preaching are so similar that, if women can prophecy, they can also preach?

Comment: I am not supposing women can't prophecy. The reason I have a question about this is: I am reading a commentary that says Philips daughters were also evangelists like their father. Claiming the Greek indicates they were regularly used in this ministry, whether the gift of prophecy or preaching the gospel. Making a connection to women preachers. Both being under the inspiration of the Holy Spirit. I am wanting to understand this if appropriate.

Comment: Yes, I understood that you agree that women can prophesy. The difficulty lies in assuming that it is equal to preaching, so that if a woman can prophesy, she can also preach. That is what needs to be substantiated first. I have not voted to have your Q closed.

Answer (score 1):

Female prophets of God are well documented in both the Old and the New Testament. The OP mentions **Philip's daughters**:

> On the next day we resumed the trip and came to Caesarea, where we
> went to the house of Philip the evangelist, who was one of the
> Seven, and stayed with him. 9 He had four virgin daughters gifted
> with prophecy. (Acts 27:9)

- Another New Testament prophetess was **Anna**, in Luke 2:

> 36 There was also a prophetess, Anna, the daughter of Phanuel, of the
> tribe of Asher. She was advanced in years, having lived seven years
> with her husband after her marriage, 37 and then as a widow until she
> was eighty-four. She never left the temple, but worshiped night and
> day with fasting and prayer. 38 And coming forward at that very time,
> she gave thanks to God and spoke about the child to all who were
> awaiting the redemption of Jerusalem.

- A third NT prophetess was **Elizabeth**, who prophesied when she was visited by Mary :

> When Elizabeth heard Mary’s greeting, the infant leaped in her womb,
> and Elizabeth, filled with the holy Spirit, 42 cried out in a loud
> voice and said, “Most blessed are you among women, and blessed is the
> fruit of your womb. 43 And how does this happen to me, that the mother
> of my Lord should come to me? 44 For at the moment the sound of your
> greeting reached my ears, the infant in my womb leaped for joy. 45
> Blessed are you who believed that what was spoken to you by the Lord
> would be fulfilled.” (Luke)

- **Mary** as a prophet. Christians do not normally think of Jesus' Mother Mary as a prophetess, but she may be considered so by the fact that she engaged in direct communication with an angel and acted upon it, much as the OT prophets did. Her Magnificat (Luke 1:46-55) may also be considered as a hymn uttered under divine inspiration.

If we turn to the OT the examples are even more explicit and numerous.

- **Miriam**. Then the prophet Miriam, Aaron’s sister, took a tambourine in her hand, while all the women went out after her with tambourines, dancing. (Exodus 15:20)
- **Deborah**. At that time the prophet Deborah, wife of Lappidoth, was judging Israel. (Judges 4:4)
- **Isaiah's wife**.  Then I went to the prophetess and she conceived and bore a son. (Isaiah 8:3)
- **Huldah**.  So Hilkiah the priest... went to Huldah the prophet, wife of Shallum, son of Tikvah, son of Harhas, keeper of the wardrobe; she lived in Jerusalem, in the Second Quarter. (2 Kings 22:14)

[Jewish tradition](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13194-sarah-sarai) also considers Sarah, Hagar, Rebekah and several other wives of the patriarchs, as well as Hannah the mother of Samuel, as prophets, either because they received direct communication from God, or because they are on record as predicting providential events.

### Resolving the difficulty

Christians understandably struggle with the tension between the fact of women prophets and NT admonitions about male leadership or women keeping silent in church. We may consider, however, that prophets like Deborah, Huldah, Elizabeth and Mary were able to perform their roles as wives and mothers perfectly well while also carrying out prophetic duties. Deborah not only prophesied but "judged Israel."

The issue of keeping silent in church is more difficult. One way to deal with it is to see women as prophesying elsewhere, but not during church meetings. Another is with reference to [textual criticism and contextualization](https://www.christianitytoday.com/scot-mcknight/2020/march/kelly-edmiston-and-women-in-churches-of-christ.html) of the biblical message. Some Christian scholars believe that the passages in question are [later additions to the text](https://www.christiantoday.com/article/apostle-paul-never-said-women-should-remain-silent-scholars-claims-controversial-passage-was-added-later/114255.htm). Others affirm that Paul's writings about women as speakers or leaders in church were written at certain time and place. They need not be taken as Law for all time.

**Conclusion: Women definitely prophesied with God's approval in both the Old and New Testaments. Such activity need not subvert their roles as wives and mothers, nor does it necessarily conflict with one's ideas about male leadership in church.**

Answer (score 1):

**Women Ministers** Not only from the New Testament, but from two thousand years of Church history, it is more than apparent that "women" do have legitimate spiritual ministries (*charismata* ,Gk.):  prophesying, physical healings, words of knowledge, hospitality, etc.  (Romans 12:6-8)

As well, they have a tremendous responsibility to minister to their husbands and young ladies, as well as children...in ways a man could never do. (Titus 2:3-5). They have their plate full!

When it comes to public ministry in the congregation, Paul's concern was the issue of **authority over men**, and **commotion**. The second issue first, Paul is dealing with *Inquiries* while the church service is going on. (1 Corinthians 14:35) This whispering, buzzing, or even outright taking that distracts from others listening to the Word preached is not to be allowed.

The other issue about holding any office (ministry) that was seen to be a place of "Authority" over men was not to be allowed.  It is unnatural (Ephesians5:22-24). No more than a Church should tell Jesus what to do, so neither should a woman rule over men. But if a woman can exercise a spiritual gift in the congregation without "ruling", there has been no problem for women to minister. Eldership, lead pastor, administration, are out of the question. But prophesying, tongues, healing, exhortation, etc. are valid...and much appreciated!

Recall that the synagogues from which the Christians first came from did not have women elders or presidents. So Paul only speaks of men when giving the necessary qualifications for this ministry. (Titus 1:5-9)  And though there were many women who followed Jesus throughout His ministry as faithful disciples, God only chose men to be Apostles.

None of this degrades or depreciates women or their valuable ministries. Men and women are complementary...of necessity, in the home, and in the Church! Women can prophesy...women can "exhort" and share their insights of the Word (preach?). But not in a ruling capacity. Peace be multiplied!

Answer (score 0):

Ancient Jewish and Israelite culture was both agrarian and patriarchal.  Roman customs were less agrarian but extremely patriarchal to the point of misogynistic.  In contradistinction to the surrounding culture, let us observe the following:

- The ancient Israelite patriarchal society did not prevent women from inheriting property.  Num 27:1-11, 36:1-12, Josh 17:3-6.
- Women could be significant leaders, eg., Deborah.  Judges 4.
- Women could be prophets of God; eg, Miriam (Micah 6:4, Ex 15:20, 21), Deborah (Judges 4:4), Huldah (2 Kings 22:14-20), Isaiah’s wife (Isa 8:3), Anna (Luke 2:36), Elizabeth (Luke 1:41-45), the four daughters of Phillip (Acts 21:8, 9), etc.
- Women could buy and sell property.  Prov 31:16.
- Women could earn independent income and use it at their discretion.  Prov 31:11, 16, 18, 20, Acts 16:12-15, 40.
- Men were required to treat women and wives with great respect.  In fact, they were to treat wives as Jesus would love them – enough to give His life for them.  Eph 5:25.
- A man could not divorce his wife on whim and marry another without being guilty of adultery.  Matt 19:9 (very different from Roman law), Gen 2:24.
- A man could not deprive his wife of marital privileges.  1 Cor 7:2-4.  (The same was equally required of women.)
- Paul had female co-workers in Euodia and Syntyche (Phil 4:2, 3) as well as Junia the apostle (Rom 16:7).  Nympha appears to be the leader of the church that met in her house at Laodicea (Col 4:15).  John also addressed an epistle to a female church leader (2 John 1).
- In addition to the above, women could hold other offices such as deaconess or “minister” (Rom 16:1).
- The New Testament church was specifically instructed to care for elderly women who could not support themselves .  1 Tim 5:9-13.
- Women were allowed to teach men.  The female leader, Priscilla taught the Apostle Apollos “more adequately”, Acts 18:26.  It is significant that Priscilla is listed before her husband, Aquila, in this passage.  King Lemuel was taught by his mother, Prov 31:1-9.
- Women were permitted to pray and prophesy in public meetings, 1 Cor 11:5.
- Gal 3:28 declares that all gender distinctions are out of place for the Christian congregation

There are numerous examples in the Bible of women being treated very badly, just as there are throughout history, even into modern times.  This does not make such appalling behavior acceptable, according to the above ideals.

If you question is about the "problem" in 1 Tim 2:11, 12, then I suggest you see my answer in [What is the context 1 Timothy 2?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/56112/what-is-the-context-1-timothy-2/56122#56122)

Comment: Your response is pretty much what I have been thinking. As well as the church at Philipi being founded by Lydia. I am not specifically referencing 1 Tim. 2:11, I believe it is God's ordained plan for a  man to lead a church. Culturally in that time I think there is more to it. I learned that about Priscilla as well. Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

Prophesizing and preaching is very different. Prophesizing is to convey the message of God and every word is deemed to be coming from God, and God can use anyone to prophesize, include woman. Preaching is to teach people the knowledge of God via the preacher understanding.

The OP's question may refer to 1 Timothy 2:12. If I was right, please edit to add in the question.

> 12 I do not permit a woman to teach or **to assume authority over a man** (or husband); she must be quiet. (1 Timonthy 2:12 NIV)

First of all, please do not use current feminism to judge event of 2000 years ago. I have found God value women in a perspective much advanced comparing to other ancient civilization, such as He allowed daughters to receive inheritance when their father had no son (Numbers 27:1-11), and protection by law to the widow.

It is worthnoting that Bible emphasize an order of ethics. Paul in his 1 Corinthians explained;

> 3 But I want you to realize that the head of every man is Christ, and the head of the woman is man (or husband), and the head of Christ is God.

To make it simple, it is God - Christ - man - woman. From right to left, it needs respect; from left to right, as God demands, it needs LOVE. Violating the order will create disorder in the relationship.

As I am not answering the feminism of today, I focus my point of view to 1 Timothy 2:12. If you noticed the phrase **'to assume authority over a man (or husband)'**, then you know Paul main context was not forbidding woman to preach. He was concerning while woman preached she took a higher authority over the men she taught, and this violate the order of ethics and create disorder in their relationship.

Does woman have no say in God's word? I really disagree with it. I meet many spiritual women, that they know how to keep the order, as they speak gently with man in private.